# How to get character input in C and put it in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, input, character

How can I get input from a console and put that input in an array. For example, if the input was "Input text", the array input[] would have:

I in [0]
n in [1]
p in [2]
and so on.

By the way I'm getting inputted a date in the format dd-mm--yyyy.

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: Why not read a text book? Will be quicker to learn programming

Comment: @RobertColumbia - It is homework without any effort

Comment: Who cares if it's homework?

Comment: The task is to get dd-mm-yyyy and print out the date in 1000 days. In C#. I'm doing this for fun.

Comment: If you are doing this for fun - you would have spent some effort and posted some code. If it is for home (and everybody knows this is true) then getting an answer off the internet will not do you any favours

Comment: @user264307 Read that input fgets(input, length, stdin); and use a loop int i = 0; while ( input[i] != '\0'  ){  variable[i] = input[i]; i++; }. Make sure that you have enough room inside that variable. Or do something like char variable[strlen(input)];

Comment: The reason we care that you do your own homework AND LEARN is so we are sure that when you later have to program on mission critical systems, the nuclear reactor will not explode due to your errors of ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given by [michi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4745612/michi) in the comments to my question.

> Read that input fgets(input, length, stdin); and use a loop int i = 0; while ( input[i] != '\0' ){ variable[i] = input[i]; i++; }. Make sure that you have enough room inside that variable. Or do something like char variable[strlen(input)];

fget() basically gets a pointer to a part of the array, in my case it being the beginning, in the first argument. 
The second argument specifies how many characters will be pushed in the array, in my case 11, because it also includes the null terminator '\0'.
 In the final argument it gets a document or a input, in my case the console which goes by stdin.

So knowing this the code for my question is:

```
char inputString[10]; // initialize string
fgets(inputString, 11, stdin); // put input in inputString
```

By the way, if you don't answer a question just because you believe it's homework, you're too funny to get insulted.